# Как правильно вывести переменную в теле класса (SCSS)?

Tags: sass, scss

Как правильно вывести `$style` в теле класса?

Пример:

```
$class: test;
$style: text-align: center;

.#{$class}
{
 $style
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь о стилях, то с помощью миксина:

```
$class: test;
@mixin style {
  text-align: center;
  color:red;
}

.#{$class}
{
 @include style;
}
```

[Пример codepen](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/eKYGoq?editors=1100)